# Create two separate log file from one handler with different levels

Tags: python, file, logging

I have a big project, I want to add logging to it with the python logging module.

What I want is: Log all levels *(Debug and above)* in **main.log**, and other log file takes a certain level (Which I want is Critical and error) from **main.log** and log it in **sub.log**.

So **main.log** will log every level *(Debug and above)*,
And **sub.log** log *Critical and error* levels only.

what is the best way to do that, What comes to my mind is:

- Do a function that will walk all over the **main.log** and search if there is any (Critical or Error level) in line, copy it and paste it in **sub.log** (but I am afraid this will be not efficient since I have maybe hundreds of lines)

***This is logger.py***

```
# logging.py 

import logging

from datetime import datetime
import time

FORMAT = '[%(levelname)s]: %(asctime)s : %(filename)s :%(lineno)s: %(funcName)s() =>: %(message)s'
TIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
PATH = '../../../scripts/utils/log_modules/logs/'


LOGFILE = f"logs_{datetime.now().strftime('%d%m%Y_%H%M%S')}.log"


def log(name, file_name=LOGFILE, level=logging.DEBUG):
  file_name = PATH + file_name

  logger = logging.getLogger(name)
  logger.setLevel(level)

  formatter = logging.Formatter(FORMAT, TIME_FORMAT)

  file_h = logging.FileHandler(file_name)
  file_h.setFormatter(formatter)
  logger.addHandler(file_h)

  return logger


# two files separate
```

and here I call the function and create an object, and start logging:
***module2.py:***

```
# From random module.py

from logger import *

add_log = log(__name__)
# **I don't** want to make other object from the function just one.


def foo():
    # do something
    add_log.info("done correctly")      # This will be logged in Main log Only
    add_log.erorr("There is an error")  # This will be logged in Main.log  And Sub.log TOO


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a second handler to your logger, and have the `logging` machinery to handle everything:

```
def log(name, file_name=LOGFILE, level=logging.DEBUG):
  file_name = PATH + file_name

  logger = logging.getLogger(name)
  logger.setLevel(level)

  formatter = logging.Formatter(FORMAT, TIME_FORMAT)

  # build and add main handler
  file_h = logging.FileHandler(file_name)
  file_h.setFormatter(formatter)
  logger.addHandler(file_h)

  # build and add sub handler
  file_h = logging.FileHandler('sub_' + file_name)
  file_h.setFormatter(formatter)
  file_h.set_level(logging.ERROR)
  logger.addHandler(file_h)

  return logger
```

Comment: This was a great answer, I have one more question, can I add something like this:
After I found an error in sub.log I want to know where exactly  this error happened in main.log so I can trace it and figure out what was happened in the app.

Comment: @MoaazAlnouri: not directly, but using the timestamp, it is easy to find a line in a log file, and the timestamp will be exactly the same in both files.

Comment: One last question :D, Do you think this is a good way for logging (create two log files one for all levels and one just for errors and critical so we can find easily if there is an error or not)

Comment: @MoaazAlnouri: **You** asked for it ;-) AFAIK, it is not very common because tools like grep at great at extracting data from log files. But it is used when debug logs become quickly very large: the normal config only logs errors and above, and when a problem occurs, the logging config is adjusted to log for a short period at the debug level in a alternative log file. Anyway, it really depends on your actual use case and procedures...